# In Python, how to add a keyword argument to a function with *args and **kwargs?

Tags: python

Let's suppose I at first have a function with a variable number of positional and keyword arguments, like this:

```
def print_stuff(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Args: {args}".format(args=args))
    print("Kwargs: {kwargs}".format(kwargs=kwargs))
```

I would like to add a keyword argument `maybe`, which I tried like this:

```
def print_stuff(*args, **kwargs, maybe=False):
    print("Args: {args}".format(args=args))
    print("Kwargs: {kwargs}".format(kwargs=kwargs))
    if maybe:
        print("Maybe!")
```

However, I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I have considered rewriting it as

```
def print_stuff(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Args: {args}".format(args=args))
    print("Kwargs: {kwargs}".format(kwargs=kwargs))
    maybe = kwargs.pop('maybe', False)
    if maybe:
        print("Maybe!")
```

but I find this not so aesthetically pleasing because the argument `maybe` is no longer in the `def` line, so to see all the possible arguments you have to read the entire function body.

Is there any more elegant way to do this? (I had a look at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls but none was immediately clear to me).

Comment: You mean `def print_args(*args, maybe=False, **kwargs)`

Comment: I tried that, but that also leads to a `SyntaxError`. (It does work if there are no `*args`).

Comment: Then you must have an error some place else. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, it works in Python 3. (I had forgotten to run the script with `python3`).